# continue qcut for next groupby group if fails?

Tags: pandas

I apply qcut on groupby results, following is a simplified version of my problem:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                  'B': [0,0,0,0,2,3,7,6]})
a.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2))
```

The issue is, some of the group raises ValueError because

```
raise ValueError('Bin edges must be unique: %s' % repr(bins))
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

What I want to achieve is, if qcut fails, skip(or pass 0 as results) and continue the qcut for next group.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little variation on @JohnE's answer to allow us to keep the `apply` syntax.

```
def try_qcut(x,n):
    try:
        return pd.qcut(x,n)
    except ValueError:
        return x*np.nan

a.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: try_qcut(x, 2))

0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4    [2, 4.5]
5    [2, 4.5]
6    (4.5, 7]
7    (4.5, 7]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice!  I'll leave my answer to save the +1, but this is much better.

Comment: no your answer is good too, i like how you use `join` like this to fill in the null values. maybe you could be a little more succinct with `ser = ser.append(pd.qcut(g,2))` (just my personal taste), also you better add `.astype(str)` otherwise it won't work with more than one non-failing group

Comment: Yeah, good point, append is cleaner.  But `qcut` seems to return a string already so I don't know if the `astype(str)` is needed?  I played around with some examples and couldn't see a difference.

Comment: @JohnE maybe it's just the latest version but for me `pd.qcut(pd.Series([1,2,3,4]),2).append(pd.qcut(pd.Series([0,1,2,3]),2))` raises `ValueError: incompatible categories in categorical concat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to avoid the issue and answer your question. However, I'm not sure if this is really the result you're searching for:

```
a.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2) if len(x.unique())>1 else x)
```

Comment: this isn't quite right yet, it only works because the example dataframe contains all zeros in the first group, `x*np.nan` works tho

Comment: also `len(x.unique())>1` is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the qcut, it still fails with `pd.qcut([0,0,0,1],2)`

Comment: if only Python had a one-liner try/except syntax !

Answer (score 1):

Not real compact, but I think this works?

```
ser = pd.Series()
for i,g in a.groupby('A')['B']:
    try:
        ser = ser.append(pd.qcut(g,2))
    except:
        pass
a.join(ser.rename('qcut'))

   A  B      qcut
0  1  0       NaN
1  1  0       NaN
2  1  0       NaN
3  1  0       NaN
4  2  2  [2, 4.5]
5  2  3  [2, 4.5]
6  2  7  (4.5, 7]
7  2  6  (4.5, 7]
```

If you prefer "0" to "NaN", replace "pass" with:

```
ser = ser.append( pd.Series( [0]*len(g) ))
```

Comment: seems the category info from qcut lost once join with a?

Comment: Well, that's instead of crashing, which is what you wanted, right?  It will only fill with qcut results for the groups where it doesn't crash.  See the note I added if you prefer to fill with "0" instead of "NaN", or you could just fix with `fillna(0)`.